# Shoenfield's Mathematical logic book Proof of Herbrand's Theorem

Tags: logic

I have trouble understanding the first lemma proof of the Herbrand's theorem section of the book. The proof of the lemma starts with a closed existential formula **A** and proves that **A** is a theorem iff **T**[$\neg$ **B**]  is inconsistent, where **B** is the matrix of **A**. Then it invokes the consistency theorem (which states that an open Theory **T** is inconsistent iff there is a quasi-tautology which is a disjunction of negations of instances of nonlogical axioms of **T** ) as a chain to prove the lemma. But to use that, shouldn't $\neg$ **B** be a non-logical axiom of **T** ? and this can't even be a case, since the lemma states that **T** is a theory with no nonlogical axioms.

[Here](http://www.cs.ru.nl/bachelorscripties/2015/Emma_Gerritse___4248120___Herbrands_theorem.pdf)'s where i take a look at to help me understand the argument. In this proof the same technique is adopted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the consistency theorem to the theory $\mathbf{T[not B]}$ rather than to $\mathbf{T}$.

Comment: Yes i eventually figured it out, i think i got some confusion about terminology by the book. Since T  has no nonlogical axioms, T[notB] has only notB as nonlogical axiom and then the consistency theorem holds there for instances of notnotB. Thank you very much!